# loop not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make equal height function in javascript , i used getElementsByName method to get it done, but its seem to be not working , i want to pick maximum height of the div and apply it other divs which have the same id

equl height function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function equalHeight () {

var get= document.getElementsByName('jj');

for (i=0;i<get.length;i++){

    var m = get[i].offsetHeight;
    alert (m)   

    var n= Math.max(m);




    document.getElementsByName('jj').style.height= n +"px";

}






    }

window.onload = equalHeight;




</script>

</head>

<body>
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:500px;">
<div style="border:solid #F00 1px; float:left; width:150px" name="jj">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

<div name="jj" style="border:solid #F00 1px; float:right; width:150px">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are already getting the element by Name before the loop I would have thought you would be able to just refer to it as `get.style.height= n +"px";` inside the loop.

Comment: have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max `.max()` takes zero or more numbers, you're giving it one number every time…

Comment: A DIV should not have a NAME attribute. IE will not match your DIVs with `getElementsByName` as IE only looks at ID, not NAME. If you change it to ID other browsers will not match as they look at NAME only. If you add NAME+ID your still using an invalid attribute, choose another way of fetching the elements by their ID.

Comment: Using getElementsByTagName and className it could be solved and I've gave an answer, hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "equalHeight" function should be:

```
var get = document.getElementsByTagName('div'), 
    maxHeight = 0, i;

for (i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {

    var m = get[i].offsetHeight;
    if (m > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = m;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < get.length; i++) {

    get[i].style.height = maxHeight + "px";
}
```

div not support the name attribute, you can put all the div in a parent div and give the parent div an "id" just like this:

```
<div id="parent_div">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

then get the divs:

```
var get = document.getElementById("parent_div").getElementsByTagName("div");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you get height of the same element you assign a new height to. You need to get the max height first. Then assign it to all the divs. [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SWmrD/)

```js
function equalHeight () {
     var divElements = document.getElementsByName('jj'),
         maxHeight = 0,
         i = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < divElements.length; i += 1) {
         maxHeight = divElements[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight ? divElements[i].offsetHeight : maxheight; 
     }

     for (i = 0; i < divElements.length; i += 1) { 
         divElements[i].style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
     }
}
```

Comment: is there anthor way to get max height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first of all add class name to all of your divs, those you want to be equal, i.e. class="jj"

```
function equalHeight()
{
    var el=document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var maxHeight=0;
    for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++)
    {
        if(el[i].className=='jj')
        maxHeight = el[i].offsetHeight > maxHeight ? el[i].offsetHeight : maxHeight; 
    }
    for(var i=0;i<el.length;i++)
    {
        if(el[i].className=='jj')
        el[i].style.height = maxHeight + 'px';
    }
}   
window.onload = equalHeight;
```

Comment: I've mentioned getElementsByClassName not tagname.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad sorry.

Not sure your method of looping through all divs and checking for a class is especially efficient. But does anyone do this stuff without JQuery nowadays anyway ...?

Answer (score -1):

```
for (i=0 ; i<get.length;i++){
    var m = get[i].offsetHeight;
    alert (m)   // your are missing an ; here
    var n= Math.max(m);
    document.getElementsByName('jj').style.height= n +"px";   
}
```

Comment: i was just testing whether it is showing values, but i check it again it is not working